# Elasticsearch on K8S with XPack

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-x-pack

I have few queries regarding setting up ES on kubernetes as we are currently facing issues while enabling basic security in our 3 master, 2 data and 2 client node configuration
    1   Is the helm chart stable/elasticsearch supported for version 6.8.4 or 7.4.2?
    2   How can we leverage the user authentication available as a part of basic license by setting Xpack. enabled: true option? Currently using the default settings ( 3 master and 2 data nodes and 2 client), we are not able to get either pods in ready state. On disabling the xpack.enabled option, everything works as normal.
    3   Are there any other settings apart from xpack.enabled: true, to allow the statefulsets to function as expected?
    4   Is there a provision to allow the inbuilt user secrets created using Kubernetes secrets? How can we ensure that the values of these secrets are known to ES administrators?
    5   In case I want to replace the existing chart with elastic’s helm chart (as mentioned in the pre deprecation notice), how can we make sure to deploy the data nodes? Currently I am not able to see a stateful set for data nodes or any configuration.